# Extracting a field from a JSON array and using it in arg

Tags: json, jq

In JQ I am trying to extract the value "some subtitle" from the array

```
  "book": {
    "title": "Some title",
    "subtitle": "Some subtitle"
  },"
```

to use as an argument in an output. I have tried

```
--arg subtitle ".book[].subtitle"
```

but then $subtitle outputs ".book[].subtitle" as a literal text string, but using

```
--argjson subtitle ".book[].subtitle"
```

errors.

Comment: 1) Your example is not an array; it is not even valid json. 2) `--arg` is for input not output.

Comment: 1) The JSON I provided was a rough idea so everyone can see what I'm trying to achieve 2) I know that --arg is for input, I need to "input" the value of  ".book[].subtitle" in to it so I can "output" it using $subtitle.

Comment: The documentation tells you that `value` assigned by `--arg` is a string.  You can just do in your filter: `.book.subtitle as $subtitle | ...`

Comment: I've tried that, it outputs the text ".book[].subtitle" as a literal string, not the value that corresponds to .book[].subtitle (which is "some subtitle")

Comment: Edit your question to add **actual** input and **actual** commandline and **actual** output. If we can't replicate it, we can't help you. See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

Given the following JSON as input:

```
{ "book": {
    "title": "Some title",
    "subtitle": "Some subtitle"
  }
}
```

you could run the following to extract the value `"Some subtitle"`:

```
jq .book.subtitle
```